# Registro con 2 foreach PHP

Tags: php, mysql

quisiera una ayuda. Es urgente.

Tengo un registro donde realizo ventas, y como se logra ver en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un campo donde se puede añadir más, entonces estoy usando. foreach para captar tanto el campo Gas y Cantidad de gas...
Este es mi codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Registra, y registra con los datos correctos, eso si no hay problema. PERO no registra como yo quiero.
Sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo rojo, es que gas, y el azul cuantos son...
Y sale por ejemplo:

Gas1 - 2 unidades 
Gas1 - 4 unidades

Gas2 - 4 unidades 
Gas2 - 2 unidades

Cuando quiero que salgan nada más

Gas1 - 2 unidades 
Gas2 - 4 unidades

Espero sé allá entendido, quisiera una ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no pones el formulario yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:
Una variable que vaya incrementando cada que agregas un nuevo registro, en mi ejemplo la inicializo con 1.

```
    <?php

    $variable = 1;

?>

<form action="respuesta.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <?php for($variable=1; $variable<3; $variable++){ ?>
    <tr>
         <td>
         <select name="cbgas[<?php echo $variable; ?>]">
            <option value="Gas1">Gas1</option>
            <option value="Gas2">Gas2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="frmcantigas[<?php echo $variable; ?>]">
         </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Y cuanto recoges los valores del formulario seria con un solo foreach, ya que los dos arrays coinciden con los indices.

```
    <?php
$cbgas = $_POST['cbgas'];
$frmcantigas = $_POST['frmcantigas'];
$variable = 1; 
foreach($cbgas as $cobgas){
    echo $cobgas.' '.$frmcantigas[$variable].'</br>'; // aquí va tu sql
    $variable++;
}
?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: No entiendo, o sea donde dice... name="cbgas[$variable]. No deberia ser: name="cbgas[<?php $variable; ?>

Comment: Hola! cambié el código para que le des una revisada, ya lo probé y funciona, sobre lo que comentas de las etiquetas php, si el select lo tienes dentro de un echo no serian necesarias o como en mi caso que lo tengo el select en html si las lleva.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero!!!